# Зачем нужно вызывать конструктор родителя в конструкторе объекта наследующего?

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

```
function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interests, 
subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interests);

  this.subject = subject;
}
```

Почему мы не можем просто прописать, что прототипом является `Person`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что кто-то должен инициализировать поля `first`, `last`, `age`, `gender` и `interests`, а кроме конструктора родителя их инициализировать некому. Разве что можно скопировать их инициализацию - но это нарушит инкапсуляцию и принцип DRY (don't repeat youself, "не повторяйся").

Comment: Хм... Но если указать в прототипе конструктор родителя имеющий эти поля, и ничего более не делать, то обращаться можно даже без инициализации. И каждый новый объект будет обладать своим полем.

Comment: @YokoFranci но тогда у вас все учителя будут иметь одинаковые ФИО, возраст и пол.

Comment: @YokoFranci или, глядя с другой стороны, вы не знаете `first` до момента вызова конструктора `Teacher`, а потому не можете записать его в прототип. Надо записывать именно в объект, а в объект его пишет конструктор `Person`

Comment: Я понял! Большое вам спасибо. Значит, каждый новый `Teacher` будет обладать своим собственным полем (которое можно будет позже изменить отдельно для каждого нового `Teacher`), но изначально все они будут иметь одинаковые значение полей, так?

Comment: Т.е. у каждого будет поле, но начальное значение будет одинаковым (при возможности его изменить), потому что оно не устанавливается.

Answer (score 0):

**Почему мы не можем просто прописать, что прототипом является Person?** - тогда все объекты `Teacher` получат один и тот `Person`

Comment: Значит и переменные, что будут изменяться в любом из `Person` будут изменяться у всех? Если да, то спасибо!